# An error occured when installing iMessage sticker pack on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imessage-extension

I made an iMessage stickers pack on Xcode. When I tested it on my iPhone, clicking the build button and it would build successfully, but Xcode always said

> could not attach to pid ####

On my cellphone, only the pack icon is visible. The photos and GIFs I add to the are all not found. The screenshots are listed below.

[image: Screen shot of iPhone]

[image: Xcode]

I've tried the [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882329/3905233) provided by Pragnesh Vitthani but it doesn't work. The output is:

> objc[313]: Class CKPPTSubTest is implemented in both
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/ChatKit
> (0x1a5a56ae0) and /Applications/MobileSMS.app/MobileSMS (0x1000d29a0).
> One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Context not
> created!Nov 30 16:06:26  MobileSMS[313] : CGContextSaveGState:
> invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
> CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable. Nov 30 16:06:26
> MobileSMS[313] : CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context
> 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
> CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable. Nov 30 16:06:26
> MobileSMS[313] : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0.
> If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE
> environmental variable. Nov 30 16:06:26  MobileSMS[313] :
> CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see
> the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
> variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not a big issue, Please Remove Your app From Your iPhone and then Reinstall your app into iPhone.

   If you Run your app into simulator then goto on Simulator menu and select Reset content and Settings option.So your Simulator is reset and now reinstall your app in simulator.
2. and, Check out your signing identity for each target (Targets > Signing > Team).Select your signing identity.
3. and, On the device, go to Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management, tap on the profile name that authorized this app, and tap Trust.

   Hope it will help you...

Comment: Thanks. I delete the iMessage app on my cellphone but the stickers still don't show up. PS: It works in iOS Simulator.

Comment: please Check out your signing identity for each target (Targets > Signing > Team).Select your signing identity.

Comment: I set the Targets' Code Signing Identity (Debug & Release) to iOS Developer. Development Team is set to Personal Team. It still doesn't work:(

Comment: ok.pls try this,in your target (MessageExtension>Build Settings>Build Options>Enable Testability) is set to No in both Debug and Release options.

Comment: you can also set in (Build Settings>Linking>Dynamic Library Install Name) is set to "$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)"

Comment: and you should also set in (Build Settings>Linking>Dynamic Library Install Name Base)  is set to "@rpath" in both target project and MessageExtension.And you should also set in (Build Settings>Linking>Run Search paths) is set to @executable_path/../../Frameworks